# Lambek calculus, linear logic, and linear algebra

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, proof-theory, linear-logic

In his 1958 paper, *The Mathematics of Sentence Structure*, Joachim Lambek introduced the Lambek calculus. In modern terms, it could be understood as a syntax for biclosed 
monoidal categories, and he remarked that it was very similar to a calculus  for linear algebra  he had worked on with G. D. Findlay -- *Calculus of Bimodules* (apparently never published).

I am interested in papers applying Lambek-calculus style methods to linear algebra. So far, I have only found Lambek's original paper, and D. Stott Parker's 1997 paper *Schur complements obey Lambek's categorial grammar: Another view of Gaussian elimination and LU decomposition*.

1. Does anyone know of an online source for G. D. Findlay and J. Lambek's *Calculus of Bimodules*? I can't find it.
2. Can anyone point me to other papers formulating results in linear algebra in terms of the proof theory of categorial logic (and similar systems like linear logic)?

Comment: Completely off topic and unrelated to to this question (which I apologize for) but I believe you may find some interest in this question on rpg.stackexchange: [Which Article Helped Get Rid of Technobabble in RPGs?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/143651/7564). Unless I'm mistaken you wrote the article in question.